# How to resolve nodejs deprecation warning - RFC 6066

Tags: node.js, deprecation-warning, kafkajs

I am trying to create a sample nodejs app for kafkajs producer and consumer.  When I start the app, I get the deprecation error.  So, I tried with --trace-deprecation flag and get this stack trace.  How can I fix it?  I tried using different versions of kafkajs, but still keep getting this error

```
   (node:61452) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
   at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1670:15)
   at /BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/socketFactory.js:12:13
   at module.exports (/BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/socket.js:24:18)
   at /BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:240:23
   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
   at Connection.connect (/BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:167:12)
   at ConnectionPool.getConnection (/BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connectionPool.js:56:24)
   at Broker.connect (/BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/broker/index.js:86:52)
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
   at async /BitBucketRepos/node-js/SimpleProducerConsumer/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/brokerPool.js:319:9
```

I have tried with using ksfkajs version 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 2.1.0 in package.json - but keep getting the same error.

How can I eliminate this warning?

Thank you

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your NodeJS version should resolve this

https://techiedan.com/nodejs-ip-address-is-not-permitted-by-rfc-6066/

> Upgrade your NodeJS version into the newest stable release. At time of writing, this is at version 15 which should resolve this issue as I believe the IP address is now ignored in future version.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your nodejs to LTS version this is more suitable version even I have also same issue but after upgrading to LTS version I got the Answer